# Create dictionary with values as anything other than objects

Tags: objective-c

I'm asking this question as someone from a PHP background.  In php, arrays are insanely simple to create: $numberArray = array('minute'=>$minute, 'hour'=$hour) etc.

As I'm getting into Obj-c / Cocoa, I've noticed that NSArray only stores flat arrays,

```
 NSMuteableArray *numberArray = [[NSMuteableArray init] alloc];
 [numberArray insertObject:minute atIndex:0];
 // not sure if above is correct, but it's a moot point
 // Creates a non-associate array (numberArray = '1', '2', '3', etc.)
```

NSDictionary allows you to create an associate arrays, but the values must be objects.

```
 NSMuteableDictionary *numberArray = [[NSMuteableDictionary alloc] init];
 [numberArray setObject:minute forKey:@"minutes"];
// numberArray creates array of ('minute'=>minuteObject, 'hour'=>hourObject, etc.)
```

Here's my question: what array or dictionary format allows you to create an array where the VALUE is something Other than an object?  I'm trying to create a method that grabs the current time's minutes / hours and then inserts them into an array.  From that method, when I need it elsewhere in my application I can call this method and get the appropriate value from the key.  Here's my full code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [gregorianCal components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];
// Then use it
NSUInteger minute = [dateComps minute];
NSUInteger hour = [dateComps hour];

NSMutableDictionary *timeArray = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[timeArray setValue:minute forKey:@"minute"];
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong in any of my assumptions.  As someone who is new to app dev, my prior statements were more for "this is what I've learned so far, please correct me if I'm wrong" rather than "I'm right, you're wrong".

Comment: NSArray, NSDictionary and NSSet can only contain objects.  You have read the documentation correctly. There are many ways to convert non object types into NSNumber for example for storage purposes in obj c collections.  You also have the option of using C arrays directly for your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Cocoa framework, in common with many object-oriented frameworks/languages (and similar to what PHP is doing under the hood), you can only store objects in collections. To store primitive value types you wrap them as objects. For numbers the class is `NSNumber`.

Change your last line to:

```
[timeArray setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:minute] forKey:@"minute"];
```

and it should work. To get the `NSUInteger` back out you need to unwrap the `NSNumber`, something along the lines of:

```
[[timeArray objectForKey:@"minute"] unsignedIntegerValue];
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because you also gave a way to convert it back to an int.  As a side question: upon further research, is this way called Key Value Coding (KVC?)

Answer (score 1):

Both NSDictionary and NSArray store objects;  including other dictionaries and arrays.

If you want to stick a number into 'em, you need to "box" the number in an instance of NSNumber.

Your code is incorrect; you would need to do:

```
[timeArray setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:minute] forKey:@"minute"];
```

Comment: While you are completely correct, CRD gave a way to convert back to an int.  Thanks for the help!